# Error retrieving TimeStamp data with dbExpress in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, odbc, dbexpress

I am retrieving TIMESTAMP data from an SQL Anywhere database via Delphi XE2, dbExpress and ODBC.
Reading the Data throws an EConvertError saying "Ungültiges Argument zum Kodieren der Zeit" ("Invalid argument for encoding the time").

It seems to me that the dbExpress ODBC driver fills the "Fractions" field of the TSQLTimeStamp structure with a value in nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.
ODBC delivers the fraction in nanoseconds as desribed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I can do a (bad) workaround by getting the data with AsSQLTimeStamp and dividing the value with 1000000.

Is this a bug in the dbExpress ODBC-Driver?
Or is there some strange flag or parameter that I have to set to get the "fractions" in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago i posted this issue to the Embarcadero bug reporting portal.

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23494

It is now marked as "Resolved" for Delphi 10.3.2. I did not try this version yet but i will confirm it works when i do.